# Angular error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, typescript

So I have a Component.html that includes an input as follows:

```
<input type="text" (change) = "setNewUserName($event.target.value)"/>
```

the component.ts is:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector : 'app-users-list',
    templateUrl : './usersList.component.html'
})
export class UsersListComponent 
{
   setNewUserName (userName : string): void {
       console.log('setNewUserName', userName)
   }
}
```

and finally the module.ts is:

```
@NgModule ({
    declarations: [UsersListComponent],
    imports : [CommonModule],
    exports: [UsersListComponent]
})
export class UsersListModule {}
```

When running the server, the following error pops up:

```
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

1 <input type="text" (change) = "setNewUserName($event.target.value)"/>
                                                              ~~~~~
```

Comment: Why are you not using ```([ngModel])``` if this is reactive form then you can check under ```AfterViewInit``` ```this.reactiveForm.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
    console.log('form value changed')
    console.log(x)
})``` you can use this.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you are referring to. This is actually my very first angular app so I'm a newbie.

Comment: use the "safe" operator `?`: `setNewUserName($event.target?.value)`. BTW, you can use [(ngModel)] to binding in two direction -or [ngModel] (ngModelChange)-

Comment: I tried the safe operator and I also tried using this.value but they are all returning errors

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Are you using Angular Ivy? Most possibly it's due to the [template type checking](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#phase-3-template-type-checking) in Ivy AOT.

Nevertheless, there are multiple options

#### Option 1: Send the event as argument

```html
<input type="text" (change) = "setNewUserName($event)"/>
```

```js
export class UsersListComponent {
    setNewUserName(event: Event): void {
      console.log('setNewUserName', (event.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value);
    }
}
```

#### Option 2: Use a template reference variable

```html
<input #userName type="text" (change) = "setNewUserName(userName.value)"/>
```

```js
export class UsersListComponent {
   setNewUserName (userName : string): void {
       console.log('setNewUserName', userName)
   }
}
```

#### Option 3: Disable type checking using [`$any()`](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any)

```html
<input type="text" (change) = "setNewUserName($any($event.target).value)"/>
```

```js
export class UsersListComponent {
   setNewUserName (userName : string): void {
       console.log('setNewUserName', userName)
   }
}
```

#### Option 4: Template-driven or reactive form

Use a [template-driven](https://angular.io/guide/forms) or [reactive](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) form to get the input value. IMO this would be the most elegant approach.

**Update:** add [disable type checking](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any)

Comment: the second solution actually worked. Why is the $ commands not working? How do I fix this please?

Comment: Did the first solution ("Send the event") not work?

Comment: The error is possibly because with Ivy, the rendering engine needs to access the properties before hand which in this case would not be possible due to the event's nature.

Comment: But with the first solution it's not an issue since the property `value` is only evaluated during runtime when the `change` event is triggered.

Comment: No it worked actually. There was I typo error. Thank you so much

Comment: option 3 work for me

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
setNewUserName($any($event.target).value);
```

it will work

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me

($any($event.target).value);

in angylar 13

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).