# PrimeNg Global Filter

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to create the table in primeNg and apply globle filter on whole table.But it show the error

```
Error: src/app/components/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:37:87 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.  

37                 <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt1.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" placeholder="Search keyword" />
```

Below code as  i follow:

```
<p-table #dt1
    [value]="applications"
    dataKey="id"
    [rows]="10"
    [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50]"
    styleClass="p-datatable-applications p-datatable-gridlines"
    [paginator]="true"
    currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
    [filterDelay]="0"
    [globalFilterFields]="['comments','applications.quote','applicationDate','effectiveDate','policyType',
    'applicantName','applicantAddress','agencyCode','agency','status']">

    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
        <div class="p-d-flex">
            <span class="p-input-icon-left p-ml-auto">
                <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
                <input type="text" pInputText (input)="dt1.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" placeholder="Search keyword" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67123603/angular-error-ts2531-object-is-possibly-null)